# MapReduce ERROR UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run following MapReduce code in my local machine:
https://github.com/Jeffyrao/warcbase/blob/extract-links/src/main/java/org/warcbase/data/ExtractLinks.java

However, I met this exception:

```
[main] ERROR UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException as:jeffy (auth:SIMPLE)   cause:java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Resource file:/Users/jeffy/Documents/Eclipse/warcbase/map_backup.txt is not publicly accessable and as such cannot be part of the public cache.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Resource file:/Users/jeffy/Documents/Eclipse/warcbase/map_backup.txt is not publicly accessable and as such cannot be part of the public cache.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager.setup(LocalDistributedCacheManager.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:625)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:391)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1269)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1266)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:394)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1266)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1287)
at org.warcbase.data.ExtractLinks.run(ExtractLinks.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at org.warcbase.data.ExtractLinks.main(ExtractLinks.java:270)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Resource file:/Users/jeffy/Documents/Eclipse/warcbase/map_backup.txt is not publicly accessable and as such cannot be part of the public cache.
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager.setup(LocalDistributedCacheManager.java:140)
... 14 more
```

I think this problem is because of I am trying to add a file to DistributedCache(Look at my code at Line 81-86 and Line 235). Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jinfeng, I'm having the same issue in local runs. Have you made any progress about this problem?

Comment: Hi Yitong, I tried a lot solutions, i.e, re-install stand-alone Hadoop in my machine, but still not resolved. I changed to debug at hadoop cluster.

Comment: Jinfeng: I think I found something, see my answer below. Maybe it could also help with your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've met with a similar problem while running a Hadoop 2 job with DistributedCache added in local environment. Finally the cause of my problem is that Hadoop 2 is not only verifying the path itself to have public execution & read access permission, but it also verifies that all its ancestor directories should have execution permission. In this case, if `"/"` or `"/Users"` does not have a 755 permission, the file will still fail to be added into public cache.

See method `static boolean ancestorsHaveExecutePermissions(FileSystem fs,
      Path path, LoadingCache<Path,Future<FileStatus>> statCache)`at Hadoop class [FSDownload.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/e1109fb65608a668cd53dc324dadc6f63a74eeb9/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/FSDownload.java)

One solution could be granting permission to all directories (sounds unsafe).

And a better solution is making sure all resource files to be cached are in `/tmp` folder or any other folder that defaultly have a >755 permission.

Answer (score 0):

I've met with similar problem.
I run mahout seq2sparse with tfidf in local mode. And raise error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Resource file:/root/title.tfidf/dictionary.file-0 is not publicly accessable and as such cannot be part of the public cache.

I found permission of /root is 750 by default

> drwxr-x---.  12 root  root       4096 16:04 root

So i changed permission of /root

> chmod 755 /root

then it works. so thank Yitong.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change permissions of only my home directory as following

> chmod go+rx /home/hadoop

to fix the problem as / and /home already have rx permisions for group and other users on my system. Here 'hadoop' is my linux login/user name.